# How are partial refunds stored in the WooCommerce Database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I have a simple backend management tool written in PHP that pulls orders from the WooCommerce database and presents them to our kitchen for processing deliveries.

I have always been able to highlight a table row that had a status other than `'wc-completed'` to handle any additional processing that might be needed. However, it was brought to my attention today that one particular order had been refunded for one line item.  A **partial refund** does not change the order status, so I need to pull the refund info from another table in the database.

I checked all the tables I know of related to order processing - `wp_posts`, `wp_postmeta`, `wp_woocommerce_order_items` and `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`, but no sign of any refund information.  In fact, the itemmeta contained in the last table doesn't even adjust the quantity, making my reports incorrect for partial orders like this.

When you view the order summary in the woocommerce backend, it shows a quantity of `1` for this particular item, and then a `-1` right below it.  I assume based on this, that somewhere in the database there are refund records associated with the orders, but I can't seem to find it.  Even the order total in `wp_postmeta` doesn't reflect the partial refund.

Does anyone know where this refund data is stored in the wordpress database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Partial refund orders** are stored in database like normal ones: 
In `wp_posts` table with a `'post_type' = 'shop_order_refund'` and a `'post_parent' = order_ID (number)`, where the `order_ID` is the reference to the original `'shop_order'`.

To find out which one of this refunds are partial, you need the `_refund_amount` amount value that you can find under `wp_post_meta` for this `'refund_order'` and his corresponding `'shop_order'` with the `_order_total` value too:

if  ( `'refund_order'` => `_refund_amount` ) != ( `'shop_order'` => `_order_total` ) :
then it's **partial**.

if  ( `'refund_order'` => `_refund_amount` ) == ( `'shop_order'` => `_order_total` ) :
then it's **normal** *(not partial)*.

**Notes:**

- You can have one or many partial refunds for one order.
- There is for **refund orders** an `_order_total` item in `wp_postmeta` table with a negative value that is always reflecting the positive value of `_refund_amount` item. This `_order_total` value has nothing to do with the **related parent** `'shop_order' => '_order_total'` value.

  > It's the opposite *(negative)* value of the **related parent** `'shop_order' => '_order_total'` value 
  >   **only when refund order IS NOT PARTIAL**.
- In `wp_woocommerce_order_items` and `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` tables, there is related detailed data concerning products in orders and refunded orders...

Comment: @BenMannino could you share the query, if you have, that would return all refunded orders? Partial and full?

Comment: @pakalbekim this shows partial refunds for me - part 1:

`select rp.id refund_id, rp.post_date refund_post_date, rp.post_title refund_post_title, rp.post_parent refund_post_parent, rp.post_status refund_post_status, rpm.meta_value refund_amount, op.id order_id, op.post_date order_post_date, op.post_title order_post_title, op.post_parent order_post_parent, op.post_status order_post_status, opm.meta_value order_total from $posts rp`

Comment: @pakalbekim part 2: `left join $postmeta rpm on rpm.post_id = rp.id left join $posts op on op.id = rp.post_parent left join $postmeta opm on opm.post_id = op.id where rp.post_type = 'shop_order_refund' and op.post_status = 'wc-completed' and rpm.meta_key = '_refund_amount' and opm.meta_key = '_order_total'`